# How to display the consumed message from jmslistener to my view?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, activemq-classic

```
@JmsListener(destination = MyQUEUE)
public void receiveMessage(final Message<MyObject> message) throws JMSException {
     MyObject response = message.getPayload();
    //what to do next..
}
```

I have been stuck in this problem for a while. I have 2 clients A and B. A sends message to B and B consumes the message using @JmsListener and after B consumed the message I want to display it in my view (.jsp). Can someone help me and what is the best way to implement this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered to use web sockets? That's the only way I can imaging that works. I can't tell you how this works in Spring, but there a whole chapter in the reference documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your requirements for this is; but you could perhaps add the JMS-objects/messages to a Spring `@Component/@Service` that holds the JMS-produced elements in a list (or Map with e.g long/MyObject). This is similar to:

```
class JmsPersister {
  private Map<Long, MyObject> allOfMyJmsObjects;

  public MyObject getLatest();

  public MyObject get(long timestamp);

  public List<MyObject> get();
}
```

From there, in the controller/view section - autowire the `@Component/@Service` that contains the history/current loaded JMS-element and use some kind of get/fetch methods in order to get e.g the latest submitted element and/or list of all JMS messages passed through. This tranlates in to something like this (within a controller):

```
class JmsExposerController {
   @Resource
   private JmsPersister persister;
   ...
   ...
}
```

That's how I would've solved it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try following to get the message in listener class

```
@JmsListener(destination = "inbound.queue")
public void receiveMessage(final Message jsonMessage) throws JMSException {
    String messageData = null;
    if(jsonMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage)jsonMessage;
        messageData = textMessage.getText();
    }
        //code to use messageData goes here
    }
```

Also take a look here - [Spring Jms Example](http://www.devglan.com/spring-mvc/spring-jms-activemq-integration-example)